# Python argparse: force use of a set of flags if some specific flags are present

Tags: argparse, python-3.9

I have the following specification I must follow for a side project:

```
script.py -T <token> [ -X (-C <carId> | -M <motorcycleId>) | -Y (-C <carId> | -M <motorcycleId>) | -Z (-C <carId> | -M <motorcycleId>) ] <file>
```

First, my script must have a `token` and `file` path provided at all times.

Second, the script may take one flag `-X`, `-Y` or `-Z` at a time. If any of those flags are used, the user must also provide the flag `-C <carId>` or `-M <motorcycleId>`.

I have a working script that implements this specification partially, but I couldn't come up with the logic for the second part.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
required = parser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
required.add_argument('-T', metavar='<token>', required=True)

exclusive_commands = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
exclusive_commands.add_argument('-X', action='store_true')
exclusive_commands.add_argument('-Y', action='store_true')
exclusive_commands.add_argument('-Z', action='store_true')

parser.add_argument('file', metavar='<file>')
```

How can I enforce the use of the flags `-C <carId> | -M <motorcycleId>` when the user uses any of the `-X`, `-Y`, `-Z` flags?

Comment: You could make X,Y,Z  `nargs=2` `store` Actions instead of `store_true`.

Comment: @hpaulj there is a problem with this approach.

For example: `exclusive_commands.add_argument('-X', action='store', nargs=2, metavar=('(-C | -M)', '<id>'))` would print the wanted signature `-X (-C | -M) <id>` in the script help page.

But, if I try to execute it like `script.py -T secret -X -C 123 file.txt` I get the following error: `argument -X: expected 2 arguments`.

I believe it's because Python is interpreting `-C` as another flag.

Comment: Use `script.py -T secret -X 123 file.txt`.  And don't use '-C' or '-M' in the metavars.  Those are arguments to '-X', not flags themselves.

Comment: But that changes to specification I must follow, so it's of no use. When I use `-X` it must be either `-X -C <id>` or `-X -M <id>`

Comment: Have fun writing your own parser (or post parsing checker).  `argparse` does not provide tools for doing fancy interactions.  `mutually_exclusive` is  simple, flat `xor` check.  And the more complex the specification, the harder it will be for your users.

Comment: How about putting C,M in a separate  mutually exclusive group, and then decide after parsing wheter to complain about missing values.

Comment: Indeed, I believe I have no other option then coding a custom validation to make it work. I wanted to know if perhaps there was a built-in way of dealing with that, but that's not the case.